# ractive child components

Tags: events, listener, ractivejs

I'll try and make this as short and sweet as possible.

In [Ractive.js](http://www.ractivejs.org/), how can I listen to a custom event on a component's parent.

--or--

How can I fire a custom event on all child components.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Ractive devs got back to me on this and v0.3.7 does not currently have support to be able to do this.

Comment: Been quite a while since v0.3.7. Any new responses to this question?

Comment: Is this still the case? :|